# How to find difference of items in same column by group?

Tags: tableau-api

The dataset is university rankings and I have a column 'world rank' and 'year'. I want to create a new field called 'rank difference' to see the difference in rank of universities from 2018 to 2011. Eg:

```
Name     Year   World Rank
Harvard  2011    4
Harvard  2018    5
```

For the above, rank difference would be -1. The data set contains a lot of universities and I am not sure how to perform LOD or any other solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use “if” inside a calculation to return a value in certain cases, and to evaluate to null otherwise. One phrase for this is a filtered calculation. Since aggregagation calculations like min(), max(), avg() etc silently ignore null values, you can then use filtered calculations in aggregate calculations.

So assuming your data source has one row per university per year, and that you put [University] on some shelf as a dimension, then the following calculation will get the result you’re looking for. Since you only have a row per university per year, you could just as easily use max(), sum() or avg() instead of min()

```
min(if [Year] = 2018 then [World Rank] end) - min(if [Year] = 2011 then [World Rank] end)
```

To extend, you could use a user supplied parameter instead of hard coded start and end years, or an LOD calculation to find the earliest and latest records for each university in your data set.